# Getting authentic and verified current location of user?

Tags: gps, coordinates, authentication

I am building an application that needs a user to send his current location. However, since GPS signals can be faked. I need the user current location to be authentic and verified.

I thought of using a Trusted third party like Google to verify and authenticate the user location before he can send it.

Is my solution based on a valid assumption?

Comment: it's not clear to me how google could tell where the user is if the GPS is faked

Comment: I just need a trusted third party the current location of a user. For example, I am building application that needs the location of the user. But I need that location to be authentic. Meaning that the user is not lying about his location

Comment: you could ask them to take a picture out of the window and compare it to a known picture of the location

Comment: But how would you know they actually took that picture themselves, rather than copied it from somewhere on the internet? If they can fake GPS location surely they can fake photograph metadata.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the third party has access to some additional verification information, when actually they are probably relying on the very same information that you want to use. What you've not specified is how stringent you want this verification to be. There might be ways to make it a little bit more difficult to fake a location, but how difficult do you need? Various people seem to be working on proper location verification, but all I've come across depend on the use of some kinds of additional beacon and/or inter-device trust network. Complicated!

Comment: What I wan is that a user sends his location (say at x)  to that trusted party and get a signature (proof) that his location ( at x) is true and not forged.

Comment: @HebaMohsen And how this trusted party will asses that the location is true ? Also if there are way for a trusted party to verify location, what would prevent you to do it yourself using the same method ?